# Include external repo files in maven build

Tags: maven, maven-jar-plugin

There are few externalized property file located like, which are used for DB connections for different environment. http://repo.xx.com/snapshots/a.properties http://repo.xx.com/snapshots/b.properties     http://repo.xx.com/snapshots/c.properties

During maven packging i've to include these property files in classpath in the jar created.
Any thoughts on how this can be done.